# Echo SUM of MySQL rows with foreach statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sum

I'm a little stuck on how to do this; I'm new to all this PDO stuff and not quite used to it yet. Basically, I have two tables, flights and users. I'd like to find the names of all the flights, and then look at the users table, and SUM the 'points' column where flight equals one of the flight names. This is what I have so far and I just can't progress any further

```
<?php
$qry = "SELECT * FROM flights ORDER by points DESC";
$stmt = $_dbConn->query($qry);
$flightRows = $stmt->fetchAll();

$flightTotalPoints = [];
$qry = "SELECT flight, SUM(points)  FROM users WHERE flight=:flightName ORDER by SUM(points) DESC";
$stmt = $_dbConn->prepare($qry);
foreach ($flightRows as $flight) {
    $flightName = $flight["name"];
    $stmt->execute(["flightName" => $flightName]);
    $flightTotalPoints[$flightname] = $stmt->fetchAll();
}


<?php if (!count($flightRows)): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-block"><h4 class="alert-heading">Notice</h4>No flights have been created yet
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="widget-box">
            <div class="widget-title"><span class="icon"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                <h5>Current Point Rankings</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content nopadding">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Flight Name</th>
                        <th>Points</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($flightRows as $flight): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $flight["name"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $flightTotalPoints[$flight["name"]]; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fetch the `sum` field in sql. You can add the alias to it for better clarity & get that value after `fetchAll` & then simply put it to the `$flightTotalPoints` array

```
$flightTotalPoints = [];
$qry = "SELECT flight, SUM(points) as total_sum  FROM users WHERE flight=:flightName ORDER by SUM(points) DESC";
$stmt = $_dbConn->prepare($qry); 
foreach ($flightRows as $flight) {
    $flightName = $flight["name"];
    $stmt->execute(["flightName" => $flightName]);
    $flightTotalPoints[$flightName] = $stmt->fetchAll()[0]['total_sum'];
}
```

Comment: Apart from my typo in the last $flightName (lowercase N, oops!), that worked perfectly! Many Thanks

Comment: Ahh!! Didn't notice that. Updated that. Glad it works for you.

Comment: Using aliases is good (I do it regularly), however, `$flight['SUM(points)']` will work.

Comment: I thought that at first, but don't think it will, because it's relying on a flightname string to SUM the correct points - happy to my corrected though, I'm not the expert!

Comment: @JaredFarrish yes, i completely agree; i always prefer to use the alias so that it is clearly understandable.

Comment: The only quibble I have is using "need". An alias is not needed, but it's a good practice.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yup `shouldn't use the need for alias.` Updated the answer. Thanks man!!